# Why I am getting masks with dotted grid across whole image using FCN8?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation

[Output of fcn8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk0pO.png)
I am doing binary segmentation using FCN8. I used seg-torch libraries's FCN function and using nclass as 1 and then apply sigmoid function to get output. Input image size is 256. Even when I earlier defined FCN model myself from scratch same kind of output is generated. Can someone help me to process these images to remove white dots from black background and black dots from segmented white region.

I don't know much about connectedcomponents but someone searching through them I wrote a code that somewhat made background free of black_dots but segmented region still has black dots in it. Using code
`

```
def remove_small_regions(mask, min_area_threshold):
    binary_mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(mask.astype(np.uint8), 4, cv2.CV_32S)
    filtered_mask = np.zeros_like(mask, dtype=np.uint8)
    for label in range(1, num_labels):
        if stats[label, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA] >= min_area_threshold:
            filtered_mask[labels == label] = 1
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
    filtered_mask = cv2.erode(filtered_mask.astype(np.uint8), kernel, iterations=1)
    filtered_mask = cv2.dilate(filtered_mask, kernel, iterations=1)
    return filtered_mask
```

Someone please fix it to have clear segmented region.
[output after above function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UgsG.png)

Comment: looks like artefacts from deconvolution.

Comment: Please post your input image